# How to suppress console error/warning/info messages when executing selenium python scripts using chrome canary

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am running python script (complete script link below) for selenium test using Chrome Canary. The test seems to be running fine, however, there are lots of error/warning/info messages displayed on the console.

Is there a way to suppress these messages? I have tried:
 chrome_options.add_argument("--silent"), but does not help. I am not able to find the right solution. Appreciate any help.

Python script : [Example script provided here](https://duo.com/blog/driving-headless-chrome-with-python)

Python: 3.6.3
Selenium: 3.6.0
Chrome Canary: 63.0.3239.5 (64 bit)
ChromeDriver : 2.33

[image: Console messages]

Comment: For me it doesn't happen. It may be because you are using canary build. Try using `chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-logging")`

Comment: Tried that argument but still the same. And I agree it is because of canary build as normal chrome build works fine, however, I am trying selenium with headless chrome. Thanks for reply @TarunLalwani.

Answer (score 68):

Try `options.add_argument('log-level=3')`.

```
log-level: 
Sets the minimum log level.
Valid values are from 0 to 3: 

    INFO = 0, 
    WARNING = 1, 
    LOG_ERROR = 2, 
    LOG_FATAL = 3.

default is 0.
```

Comment: Had the same kind of issue with Node.js using Protractor and headless chrome (version 65 on win64). Setting log-level=2 fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This approach evidently reduced the logs. However, there's still some logs printed, although they didn't influence the workflow. One of the logs: `[0817/100109.981:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(128)] Failed to resolve address for stun.services.mozilla.com., errorcode: -105`

Answer (score 15):

If "--log-level" doesn't work for you (as of 75.0.3770.100 it didn't for me), this should:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='<path-to-chrome>', options=options)
```

- See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2907#c3
- Code copied from [Python selenium: DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392423/python-selenium-devtools-listening-on-ws-127-0-0-1)

Answer (score 14):

Works for me in Python/Chrome...

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
```

Comment: but what if we're building the script to scale across different drivers ?

Answer (score 8):

You can take help of below link.

[List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

**"--log-level"**  sets the minimum log level. Valid values are from 0 to 3: INFO = 0, WARNING = 1, LOG_ERROR = 2, LOG_FATAL = 3.

Answer (score 5):

I have just tested this one, it works for me (C#):

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArguments("--headless", "--log-level=3");
    RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import os
os.environ['WDM_LOG_LEVEL'] = '0'
```

That code hides the console output for `from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager` console outputs

Answer (score 0):

The FULL answer is you need to turn the logging off using:-

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('log-level=3')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)  # or webdriver.Chrome(), etc.

but you cannot get rid of the console log output of:-
```

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:#####/devtools/browser*****

You'll just stop the logging of the selenium messages into the terminal/console.