# How to turn off console printing in Laravel Dusk testing?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-dusk

When I run my laravel dusk tests, the cmd displays a lot of console messages such as:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12802/devtools/browser/dbffc66a-0b29-4149-a1b5-8f20259770c2
[0720/101840.929:INFO:CONSOLE(44479)] "Download the Vue Devtools extension for a better development
experience:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools", source: http://localhost:8000/js/app.js (44479)
[0720/101840.929:INFO:CONSOLE(44490)] "You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html", source: http://localhost:8000/js/app.js (
44490)
```

How can I prevent this ? It displays this as it goes through each page while testing

Comment: This is actually a serious problem...

Answer (score 5):

This response is a little late, but I just came up with this problem now.

You can pass arguments to the Chrome driver to prevent console logging, as shown below.

On Laravel 5.8

test\DuskTestCase.php

```
...


/**
 * Create the RemoteWebDriver instance.
 *
 * @return \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver
 */
protected function driver()
{
    $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--headless',
        '--window-size=1920,1080',
        '--log-level=3', // Add this line
        '--silent' // Add this line
    ]);

    return RemoteWebDriver::create(
        'http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
            ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
        )
    );
}

...
```

This will turn off all console messages.

Comment: I added it, it does not seem to work for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: This may have [changed with v75](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57043902/6576977).

Try adding `$options->setExperimentalOption('excludeSwitches', [enable-logging']);`