# is there a method or a function to hide selenium's output from the program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, output

i have some selenium code written in python but the problem is that selenium always prints out this output at the start of a program

```
DevTools listening on ws://ip address/devtools/browser/some numbers
```

and since my computer doesn't support bluetooth i get also this output:

```
[10376:9472:1101/171134.942:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(208)] [17:11:34.941] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1076 Getting Default Adapter failed.
```

is there a way to eliminate only selenium's output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the below that I found on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744968/how-to-suppress-console-error-warning-info-messages-when-executing-selenium-pyth)

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # disable some annoying debug output to console
    options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(
        "C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you add this to your code/change your code to this, it should solve it

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service_log_path=os.devnull)
```

it should tell the selenium, that you don't want to put anything in logs