# How can I get rid of the error messages or prevent them from printing into the terminal using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys



url = 'https://ytmp3.nu/CNtD/'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

#val = input("Enter the Youtube URL of the Video ")
browser.find_element('xpath', "/html/body/form/div[2]/input[1]").send_keys("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VbJeNEwDOJg")

browser.find_element('xpath','/html/body/form/div[2]/input[2]').click()

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

[Terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa5rg.png)

I understand it has something to do with the pages SSL certificate but i want to circumvent that because I wish to ask teh user for input, and its hard to see that the terminal is asking for input when it gets lost in all the text

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46866124/7375347) help with your issue?

Comment: Tried it, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

you need to createa a chrome options and add 'ignore-certificate-errors' to the arguments

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')

brwoser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: I tried copy-pasting what you posted but it still didn't work :(

Comment: what u mean it didnt work u got an error or same problem kept happening

Comment: I get this error:
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chrome_options'

Comment: please change `brwoser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)` to `brwoser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)`