Why do I keep getting this Tensorflow related message in Selenium errors?
I'm new to Selenium, and I've been trying to write some scripts for web scraping but sometimes when I make a mistake as part of the error message I see this line:
"Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU."
for example in the latest error it was this:
"[5900:21516:0425/160524.581:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -201
Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU."
why is TensorFlow mentioned here?

Without the code that reproduces the error, I'm not sure what you want us to do with this info. Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring.

I believe the message indicates that TensorFlow can't use the GPU so it switches to CPU. (headless Selenium session?)  It's possible the site you are testing is running some WASM with Tensorflow built-in.  (or that you have something installed that uses it... webcam software maybe?)

@browsermator The Selenium session is not headless (Although I am new to Selenium and I fail to understand why a headless session specifically might use Tensorflow if you don't mind clarifying that) The site that I'm testing is Linkedin and after your comment I've found that it uses Tensorflow.js for some optimizations which might be it, although I've initially posed the question because I was suspecting malware/spyware from previous suspicious behaviour, but I've heard that's unlikely, could the webcam software in question be a piece of spyware? is there a way for me to verify either way?

I'm not suggesting anything nefarious is happening.  Just clarifying the message which basically says that TensorFlow can't use the GPU.  It's not an error message, it's only informational.  (if it's not WASM and only javascript that would be why...)  Selenium doesn't use TensorFlow as far as I know.  It's possible you are using a framework that combines Selenium and TensorFlow?  If you want code to have some ai-like abilities (say recognizing objects in images... maybe captcha images) you might do that.

From what I'm reading it's also just a convenient package for multi-dimensional arrays.  I guess when using these types of objects the GPU is more efficient, so it'll prefer to use that if it can.  I think JS CAN actually access the GPU through WebGL if the browser supports it.  (didn't know that... I thought only WebAssembly could access GPU)

@browsermator Yes, you're right Selenium doesn't use Tensorflow, It most likely is just some functionality on the Linkedin website, I guess I was just trying to err on the safe side and see if there is something I might be worried about.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I am receiving the exact same message when I run selenium. I am using selenium 4.20.0. The most interesting part is that I saw high usage of CPU. I checked and I can see Chrome tasks are using a lot of CPU. Here is the repo.

@JeffC I beleive is a totally valid question, and I think that if it doesn't include code is because the asker beleives that the problem has nothing to do with the code, maybe he is not right, but thew question isn't wrongly asked.

As browsermator already mentioned "Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU." is not an error message but simply an info (cf. https://github.com/google-ai-edge/mediapipe/issues/3017). It can therefore be suppressed by adding
options.add_argument("--log-level=1")

to your webdriver's options.

--log-level=2 worked for me

Since "Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU" is an info (log level 0), setting the log level to 1 will suppress it. Log level 2 will also suppress any warnings (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46866124/11779702). My recommendation would always be to use the lowest log level necessary to solve the problem.

For anyone just looking for an answer to the question of why/whether Selenium uses TensorFlow, some further research shows this is most likely not a Selenium info message at all but directly from Google Chrome/Chromium/ChromeDriver.
TensorFlow is a Google project created at Google Brain, and it seems recent versions of Chrome/Chromium have either started using TensorFlow or started emitting the info message - I first noticed it from around version 129. Here's an example of the message being emitted by the Google Chrome command-line interface, and here's one from MediaPipe, another Google product. Both examples were posted around the time version 129 was released.
What exactly Chrome/Chromium uses TensorFlow for would have to be answered by combing through its source code and/or documentation, but based on the above it seems definitive that this message is not related to Selenium in any way, and that Selenium itself doesn't use TensorFlow.

In my case, the code was working.
I added the line to initialize the variable
CHROME="C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

When run my existing code it gave me the message "Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU" and execution of the code stopped.
After I renamed the variable to MYCHROME, the error disappeared and script works as expected. I think, I overwrote something with my variable.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I can reproduce the problem.  My bash script produces this very same error.  Problem started today when I installed codelite as well as python3 today which seemed to change something in my system running MacOS 14.4.1
Error message that appears in my commandline window:

Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU

This simple bash script produces the error when trying to launch Google Chrome window:
#!/bin/bash

URL="www.google.com"

#open up default profile
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --profile-directory=Default

#launch the webpage
open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ $URL

